# Установка заголовков для Vibe.d WebSocket

Tags: websocket, d

Не могу понять как установить заголовки для Vibe.d WebSocket.
Подскажите как это сделать?

```
import vibe.vibe;

void main()
{
    auto ws_url = URL("wss://domain.com");

    auto ws = connectWebSocket(ws_url);

    logInfo("WebSocket connected");

    while (ws.waitForData())
    {

    }

    logFatal("Connection lost!");
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: У класса WebSocket есть свойство request типа HTTPServerRequest.
У объектов этого типа (класса) есть поле headers 
http://vibed.org/api/vibe.http.common/HTTPRequest.headers
Ещё не добрался до vibe.d, потому не могу точно сказать. 
ws.headers.addField(НУЖНЫЙ_ЗАГОЛОВОК);
Скорее всего как-то так должно быть.